# Calc II - Definite integral of sqrt(t^2 + t) from 2x to 1?

Tags: calculus, integration, derivatives, definite-integrals

How do I find

$$\int_1^{2x}\sqrt{t^2 + t}$$

with only knowledge from a Calculus I course?

I've tried plugging this puppy into Wolfram Alpha and other integral solvers, which report it as solvable (looks really long and nasty), but I think this is outside the scope of my just-entered-Calc-II knowledge and that I need to solve it in a tricky way.

The problem is part of the linked green sheet. Since I don't know how to integrate this I've tried to solve the sheet without doing so, though on part D) it seems like my luck is about to run out. I doubt what I am trying to do is even legal. Please advise.

[image: Problem Sheet]
[image: Problems Part 1]
[image: Problems Part 2]

Comment: use fundamental theorem of calculus :  $\dfrac{d}{dx} \int\limits_a^{g(x)} f(t) dt =   f(g(x)) g'(x)$ ;   for part D :   $\int \sqrt{1 + F'(x)^2}dx$. So it seems you don't really need to evaluate the integral

Comment: I don't think you need to evaluate the actual integral for the entirety of this problem. For example, part (a) is asking for $F'(x)$ as opposed to $F(x)$. You might think that you'll need to evaluate the integral to figure out what $F$ looks like in order to take the derivative, but the Fundamental Theorem of Calculus actually helps us taking derivatives of integrals directly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We have, by setting $t=2u$,
$$ F(x)=\int_{1}^{2x}\sqrt{t^2+t}\,dt = 2\int_{1/2}^{x}\sqrt{4u^2+2u}\,dt$$
so:

**a)** $$F'(x) = 2\sqrt{4x^2+2x}$$
**b)** The domain of $F(x)$ is $[0,+\infty)$, since $4u^2+2u$ is negative for any $u\in(-1/2,0)$.

**c)** $$\lim_{x\to 1/2}F(x)=0$$
since $\sqrt{4u^2+2u}$ is a continuous function in a neighbourhood of $u=1/2$.

**d)** $$L(\gamma)=\int_{1}^{2}\sqrt{1+F'(x)^2}\,dx = \int_{1}^{2}\sqrt{16x^2+8x+1}\,dx=\int_{1}^{2}(4x+1)\,dx=7.$$

Comment: In the "We have" part, it looks like you divided 2 from the integral numbers, and now there's a 2 inside the square root, and I'm already confused. Please don't skip any steps.

Comment: The beginning aside, I'm starting to see it now. You plugged in for the fundamental theorem in part A...

Comment: It was just a change of variable, hope it is more clear now.

Comment: Wouldn't (-Infinity, -1] also be part of the domain?

Comment: Nope, because you cannot integrate $g(u)=\sqrt{4u^2+2u}$ over an interval in which the square root is not defined, and, assuming that $x\leq -1$ and $F(x)$ is well defined, $$\int_{1/2}^{x}g(u)du = \int_{1/2}^{0}g(u)\,du+\color{red}{\int_{0}^{-1/2}g(u)du}+\int_{-1/2}^{x}g(u)du,$$ but the red integral makes no sense at all.

Comment: Unrelated to the last strand: Why did you do change of variables for the integral in the first place?

Comment: Because in such a way it is straightforward to get $F'(x)$. If $$G(x)=\int_{k}^{x}g(x)\,dx,$$ then $G'(x)$ is just $$G'(x) = g(x).$$

Comment: Okay. For the most part I got it. Was able to complete the green sheet using this as my guide.